# Tengo 2 window onload y uno esta anulando al otro, no se que hacer

Tags: javascript

Dejo aquí el código que tengo y el cual me está fallando pues la funciones se sobreescriben y he notado que el error está en el window onload, como puedo ponerlo de forma que uno no sobre escriba al otro, la verdad apenas estoy aprendiendo esto y desconozco la forma en la cual puedo llegar a solucionarlo, so, necesito ayuda, por favor

Ahora como está me funciona changeLogo0 y avtivateform y si quito de la función anónima el activateform y su window onload, entonces deja de funcionar esa y si funciona changeLogo0 y changeLogo1

```js
/* -----------------------------LISTENERS Y VARIABLES GENERALES------------------------------- */  
var change0;
var change1;
var activating;

window.onload=changeLogo0;
window.onload=changeLogo1;
window.onload=activateform;

addEventListener("load", () => {
    changeLogo0();
    changeLogo1();
    activateform();
});

/* ------------------------------------VARIACIÓN DE LOGO------------------------------------ */  

function changeLogo0() {

    change0=document.getElementById("logo0");
    change0.addEventListener("mouseover",dark0,false);
    change0.addEventListener("mouseout",light0,false);
}

function dark0(){
    document.getElementById("logo0").src = "assets/AMD_dark.png"; 
}

function light0(){
    document.getElementById("logo0").src = "assets/AMD_light.png"; 
}

function changeLogo1() {

    change1=document.getElementById("logo1");
    change1.addEventListener("mouseover",dark1,false);
    change1.addEventListener("mouseout",light1,false);
}

function dark1(){
    document.getElementById("logo1").src = "../assets/AMD_dark.png"; 
}

function light1(){
    document.getElementById("logo1").src = "../assets/AMD_light.png"; 
}

/* ------------------------------------ACCIONADOR DE FORMULARIO------------------------------------ */  

function activateform() {
    activating=document.getElementById("emailOn");
    activating.addEventListener("click",makeVisible,false);
}

function makeVisible() {
    document.querySelector(".form1").classList.add("hidden");
    document.querySelector(".form2").classList.add("visible");
}
```

```css
/* ------------------------------------STYLES CONTENT PAGE CONTACT------------------------------------ */

.container-form{
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 20%;
    min-height:27.2rem;
    margin-top: 13rem;
    border-left: 0.1rem solid #39296650;
    box-shadow: 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.3rem #39296650;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.4rem;
    position: relative;
}

/* STYLES FORMS */

.top-form{
    background: #392966;
    padding: 0.8rem 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.8rem;
    border-radius: 1.5rem 1.5rem 0rem 0rem;
    height: 4rem;
}

.form1{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 6rem;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: visible;
}

.form2{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 4.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.options-form1, .options-form2, .options-form3, .options-form4{
    margin: 1rem 0.3rem 0rem 0.3rem;
    min-height:5rem;
    padding-top: 0.7rem;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.250);
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 2rem;
}

.options-form1 strong, .options-form2 strong, .options-form3 strong, .options-form4 strong{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.options-form1 a, .options-form2 a{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 27%;
    margin-top: -0.7rem;
}

.options-form3{
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* CLASSES TO ADD WITH JS */

.visible{
    visibility: visible;
}
  
.hidden{
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* STYLE FORM2 */

input, textarea{
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37);
    min-height: 1.5rem;
    width: 93%;
    border: none;
    color: #4b4852af;
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 0.8rem;
}

textarea{
    height: 5rem;
}

#option-checkbox{
    width: 2%;
}

/* BUTTOM FORM2 */

#send, #send:visited{
    margin: 0.8rem 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.8rem;
    height: 2rem;
    width: 5rem;  
    background: #392966;
    color: #d6d3de;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#send:hover{
    background: #d25812;
    color: #d6d3de;
}

#send:active{
    background: #d25812;
    color: #d6d3de;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
/* -----------------------------pagina index------------------------------- */ 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script language="javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <title>HOME</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper layout1">

        <div class="cell cell1">

            <div class="sidebar">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/AMD_light.png" alt="logoLigh" id="logo0"></a>
                <div class="vl"></div>
                <ul class="rrss">
                    <li><a href="https://wa.me/34675153963"><img src="assets/RRSS_WP.png" alt="iconWhatsapp"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/adriana_mmd/"><img src="assets/RRSS_IG.png" alt="iconIG"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/adriana-michell-moncada-duran-96749b1aa/"><img src="assets/RRSS_LI.png" alt="iconLIn"></a></li> 
                    <li><a href="mailto:amd.creativedesign1@gmail.com"><img src="assets/RRSS_GM.png" alt="iconGmail" id="GM"></a></li>    
                </ul> 
            </div> 

        </div>

        <div class="cell cell2">

            <div class="intro">
                <h1 class="slidein1">hola!</h1>
                <h2 class="slidein2">soy tu futura diseñadora creativa</h2>
                <h2 class="slidein3">Adriana Michell Moncada Duran</h2>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="cell cell3">
            
            <div class="header">        
                <ul class="navigation">
                    <li id="e1"><div class="circulo c1"></div><a href="pages/bio.html">bio</a></li>
                    <li id="e2"><div class="circulo c2"></div><a href="pages/portafolio.html">portafolio</a></i>
                    <li id="e3"><div class="circulo c3"></div><a href="pages/contacto.html">contacto</a></li>
                </ul> 
            </div>
        
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html> 

/* -----------------------------página contacto----------------------
--------- */  

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="../css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script language="javascript" src="../js/main.js"></script>
    <title>CONTACTO</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper layout1">

        <div class="cell cell1">

            <div class="sidebar">
                <a href="../index.html"><img src="../assets/AMD_light.png" alt="logoLigh" id="logo1"></a>
                <div class="vl"></div>
                <ul class="rrss">
                    <li><a href="https://wa.me/34675153963"><img src="../assets/RRSS_WP.png" alt="iconWhatsapp"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/adriana_mmd/"><img src="../assets/RRSS_IG.png" alt="iconIG"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/adriana-michell-moncada-duran-96749b1aa/"><img src="../assets/RRSS_LI.png" alt="iconLIn"></a></li> 
                    <li><a href="mailto:amd.creativedesign1@gmail.com"><img src="../assets/RRSS_GM.png" alt="iconGmail" id="GM"></a></li>    
                </ul> 
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="cell cell2">

            <div class="wrapper-second layout2 contentContact fadein">

                <div class="cell-s">

                    <div class="container-text">
                        <h2>Contacto</h2>
                        <div class="hz"></div>
                        <p>Siéntete libre de contactar por cualquiera de los canales que pongo a tu disposición, incluso si no puedo llevar a cabo tu requerimiento podre recomendarte la persona adecuada.</p>
                     </div>

                </div>

                <div class="cell-s">

                    <div class="container-form">
                        <div class="top-form">
                            <h4><strong>¡Let’s talk about it!</strong></h4>
                            <h3>Tienes una necesidad del diseño, estaré</h3>
                            <h3>encantada de ayudar...</h3>                     
                        </div>

                        <div class="form1">
                            <p id="description">Elige la modalidad que mejor se adapte a ti:</p>
            
                            <div class="options-form1">
                                <a href="#" target="_blank" id="link"></a>
                                <p><strong>Llamada</strong></p>
                                <p>Por teléfono - 15 min</p>
                            </div>
            
                            <div class="options-form2">
                                <a href="#" target="_blank" id="link"></a>
                                <p><strong>Online</strong></p>
                                <p>Vía Google Meet - 30 min</p>
                            </div>
            
                            <div class="options-form3" id="emailOn">
                                <p><strong>Email</strong></p>
                                <p>Haz clic aqui para redactar y enviar</p>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
            
                        <div class="form2" id="emailSend">
                            <div class="options-form4">
                                <form action="/action_page.php">
                                <p><strong><label for="user">Nombre:</label></strong></p>
                                <input type="text" id="user" name="user">
                                
                                <p><strong><label for="email">Email:</label></strong></p>
                                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="">
                                
                                <p><strong>Mensaje</strong></p>
                                <textarea name="textarea" rows="10" cols="100">  Escribir aqui</textarea><br>
            
                                <input type="checkbox" name="option-checkbox" id="option-checkbox" value="checkbox">
                                <label><i>He leído y acepto las políticas y aviso legal*</i></label><br>
            
                                <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="send"><br>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            
                    </div>
            
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="cell cell3">
            <div class="header">        
                <ul class="navigation">
                    <li id="e1"><div class="circulo c1"></div><a href="bio.html">bio</a></li>
                    <li id="e2"><div class="circulo c2"></div><a href="portafolio.html">portafolio</a></i>
                    <li id="e3"><div class="circulo c3"></div><a href="contacto.html">contacto</a></li>
                </ul> 
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: El código de la pregunta se editó incorporando el código de la respuesta. Ya no hacen sentido para los próximos visitantes.

Comment: @ffflabs Pasa más a menudo de lo que crees, es una pena, pero los nuevos usuarios no saben como hacerlo bien muchas veces y destrozan las preguntas perdiendo todo el sentido de las mismas.  En esos casos, cuando ya han conseguido lo que quieren, termino pidiendoles que las borren enteras porque ya son infumables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás redefiniendo la propiedad, haciendo que solamente se ejecute el segundo, no es como que espere a que uno se ejecute y después se ejecute el otro, le estás diciendo que cuando cargue la ventana se ejecute una función, no se ejecutará otra bajo el mismo criterio si la ventana ya renderizó. Lo que puedes hacer es crear una función anónima que ejecute tus dos funciones.

```
addEventListener("load", () => {
    changeLogo0();
    changeLogo1();
});
```

Comment: OMG creo que te amo, le he pasado capturas del código a mi profe y no me decía nada, imaginaba que la solución era una tontería, porque siempre 'para el que sabe' lo es, pero como yo apenas y se algo, pues estaba dando vueltas en circulo sin conseguir la solución, gracias

Comment: @Adri Si esta respuesta resuelve tu pregunta deberias aceptarla para que la pregunta no quede pendiente eternamente. Mira este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) para aprender a aceptar respuestas. Tambien te recomiendo que te leas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y como funciona el tema de preguntas/respuestas. Gracias!

Comment: @masterguru Pregunta, dentro de la función anónima puedo tener allí dentro más de 2 variables?

Comment: No se por donde va esa pregunta, pero dentro de una función puedes tener lo que quieras. En este caso lo que hay son llamadas a otras dos funciones.

Comment: @masterguru es que he agregado una función más y la he puesto dentro de la función anónima como me indicaste antes, pero solo me funcionan 2 de as 3, he actualizado mi pregunta principal y su código para que lo puedas ver si te es posible, por favor

Comment: @Adri pon el html con todos los elementos que llamas en tu javascript en la pregunta tambien para que pueda copiarlo y hacer pruebas, sino va a ser dificil que pueda ayudarte

Comment: @masterguru ya he agregados el html y el css que llaman mi js, ya me dices

Comment: @Adri Diria que tu problema ahora es que estas intentando usar las mismas 3 funciones en dos páginas distintas donde no aparecen todos los elementos con los id a los cuales haces referencia a la vez, y eso provoca que dejen de funcionar por dar un error en consola. No podemos extender demasiado más este tema en los comentarios, pero de momento en cada página intenta usar las funciones que sepas que tienen los elementos en ella y no todas si sabes que no estan. Si aún así te surgen nuevos problemas abre una nueva pregunta con todos los datos de nuevo, gracias.

Comment: @masterguru gracias, he detectado el error, no era del tipo que mencionabas, gracias igualmente ;)

Comment: De nada, me alegro por ti pues!  Saludos